# Magento 2: Send custom email programmatically

Tags: magento2, email

I am using Magento 2.2.2

I have one form on my website with the fields "Name" and "Email". Now when the customer submits the form I want to send an email to the email address filled by the customer.

I want to send custom HTML in this email and this HTML includes images. How can I achieve this?

I have used below code:

```
<form class="form"  method="post" name="form_1" id="form_1" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="formdiv">
        <h2>Custom Form</h2>
    </div>

    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required="required" placeholder="Enter Your Name" />

    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="email_share" name="email_share" required="required" placeholder="Enter Your Email" />

    <input type="submit" id="submit_result" name="submit_result" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit_result']))
{


$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$to = "test@gmail.com";
$nameTo = $_POST['txtname'];
$transport = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder'); 
$data = $transport
    ->setTemplateIdentifier(7)
    ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => 1])
    ->setFrom(['name' => 'Test','email' => 'test1@gmail.com'])
    ->addTo($to,$nameTo)
    ->getTransport();
$data->sendMessage();



}
?>
```

And below as well:

```
<form class="form"  method="post" name="form_1" id="form_1" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="formdiv">
        <h2>Custom Form</h2>
    </div>

    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required="required" placeholder="Enter Your Name" />

    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="email_share" name="email_share" required="required" placeholder="Enter Your Email" />

    <input type="submit" id="submit_result" name="submit_result" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit_result']))
{

$to = "test1@gmail.com";
$nameTo = $_POST['txtname'];
$from = "test@gmail.com";
$nameFrom = "test";

$body ="<table cellpadding='4' cellspacing='0' style='border-collapse:collapse' width='500' border='1'>";
$body.="<tr><td align='left' colspan='2' style='background:#CCC;'><strong>Test email</strong></td></tr>";
$body.="<tr><td width='150' align='left'>Name</td><td align='left'>".$_POST['name']."</td></tr>";
$body.="<tr><td width='150' align='left'>Email</td><td align='left'>".$_POST['email_share']."<br /></td></tr>"; 
$body.="</table>";

$email = new \Zend_Mail();
$email->setSubject("Test Request");
$email->setBodyHtml($body); 
$email->setFrom($from, $nameFrom);
$email->addTo($to, $nameTo);
$email->send();     


}
?>
```

I have tried both logics but they are not working

Comment: Are you using controller for this feature?

Comment: Everyone, I have edited my question. Please check

Comment: You can create a module for this, instead of using 
**$objectManager** directly in your phtml file.

Answer (score 3):

I've done this by creating below post controller for the custom form to send data with attachment in Magento 2.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;

class Post extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT = 'rga/email/recipient_email';
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER = 'rga/email/sender_email_identity';
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE = 'rga/email/email_template';


    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $_transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface
     */
    protected $inlineTranslation;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper
     */
    protected $_escaper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\File\UploaderFactory
     */
    protected $uploaderFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_escaper = $escaper;
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Post user question
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        if (!$post) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }

        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
        try {
            $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
            $postObject->setData($post);

            $error = false;
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }

            $photos = array();
            foreach ($_FILES['photo']['name'] as $key => $image) {

                if (empty($image)) {
                    continue;
                }

                $fileName = '';
                if (isset($_FILES['photo']['name'][$key]) && $_FILES['photo']['name'][$key] != '') {
                    try {
                        $target = $this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('rga');
                        $fileName = $_FILES['photo']['name'][$key];
                        $fileExt = strtolower(substr(strrchr($fileName, "."), 1));

                        $fileNamewoe = rtrim($fileName, $fileExt);

                        $fileName = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $fileNamewoe) . time() . $key . '.' . $fileExt;
                        if (!in_array($fileExt, array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'))) {
                            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Only jpg, jpeg, png and gif file types are allowed.'));
                            session_write_close();
                            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                            return;
                        }
                        array_push($photos, $fileName);
                        $uploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'photo['.$key.']']);
                        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif']);
                        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                        $uploader->save($target,$fileName);
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        $error = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($error) {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later'));
                session_write_close();
                throw new \Exception();
            }

            $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeScope)) // this code we have mentioned in the email_templates.xml
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, // this is using frontend area to get the template file
                        'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
                    ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
                ->setFrom($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER, $storeScope))
                ->setReplyTo($post['EmailAddress'])
                ->addTo($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT, $storeScope));

            /* add photos to attachment; */
            foreach($photos as $pic) {
                $attachmentFilePath = $this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('rga').'/'. $pic;
                if(file_exists($attachmentFilePath)){
                    $transport->addAttachment(file_get_contents($attachmentFilePath,$pic));
                }
            }

            $transport = $transport->getTransport();           
            $transport->sendMessage(); 
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                __('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.')
            );
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addError(
                __('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later.')
            );
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

For whole module with email template, you can follow the below artice

> https://www.brainacts.com/blog/magento-2-how-to-send-email-programmatically

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: Your answer is right and appropriate as well +1 for that

Comment: @MuhammadHasham Thank you for appreciation.

Answer (score 3):

**Try below code:**

> {{Namespace}}/{{Module Name}}/etc/email_templates.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../Email/etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="custom_email_template" label="Email Form" file="custom_email.html" type="html" module="Your_ModuleName" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

> {{Namespace}}/{{Module Name}}/Controller/yourcontroller.php

```
/**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $_transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
    */
    protected $_storeManager;


    public function __construct(
        ...
        ...
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        ...
        ...
    )
    {
        ...
        ...
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->_storeManager     = $storeManager;
        ...
        ...
    }

    public function YourCustomFuction($email,$name){
        $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        $template   = "custom_email_template";

        /* Receiver Detail  */
        $receiverInfo = [
        'name' => $name,
        'email' => $email,
        ];


        /* Sender Detail  */
        $senderInfo = [
            'name' => 'XYZ',
            'email' => 'xyz@angara.com',
        ];

        $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($template);
        $transport = [
            'name'           => $name,
            'email'           => $email,
        ];
        $this->_transportBuilder->setFrom($senderInfo);
        $this->_transportBuilder->addTo($receiverInfo['email'],$receiverInfo['name']);
        $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateVars($transport);
        $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateOptions(['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $store]);
        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();


    }
```

> {{Namespace}}/{{Module Name}}/view/frontend/email/custom_email.html

```
<!--@subject {{var name}}, Your subject line @-->

<p>Your custom email content here</p>
```

**I hope it will help...!!!**

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume your custom html is

`/app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/email/modulename/test.html`

```
<div>

Hello, this is a test email.

</div>
```

Declare your email template, create xml file
`/app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/email_templates.xml`

with content:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:Magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="modulename_test_template" label="Test email" file="modulename/test.html" type="html" module="VendorName_ModuleName" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

Finally, create a function to send your email.
I am using a controller action. Create file:

`/app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Controller/Index/Sendemail.php`

with content:

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Controller;

use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class Sendemail extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http
     */
    protected $_request;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $_transportBuilder;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
        , \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
        , \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
        , \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    )
    {
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('modulename_test_template')
            ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $store])
            ->setTemplateVars(
                [
                    'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore(),
                ]
            )
            ->setFrom('general')
            // you can config general email address in Store -> Configuration -> General -> Store Email Addresses
            ->addTo('customer@email.com', 'Customer Name')
            ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: I have a custom form in .phtml file in the theme folder. So how can I call execute function when the customer clicks on submit button?

Comment: @ChintanKaneriya your form is definitely going to request on some controller then in that case add my controller code in your target controller like `$transportBuilder` and `$storeManager` in your controller `__construct` and use it like I did

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing via only phtml than try with php mail function. This is the basic way to send mail.

```
$to = "test1@gmail.com";
$nameTo = $_POST['txtname'];
$from = "test@gmail.com";
$email_subject = "Test mail";
$body ="<table cellpadding='4' cellspacing='0' style='border-collapse:collapse' width='500' border='1'>";
$body.="<tr><td align='left' colspan='2' style='background:#CCC;'><strong>Test email</strong></td></tr>";
$body.="<tr><td width='150' align='left'>Name</td><td align='left'>".$_POST['name']."</td></tr>";
$body.="<tr><td width='150' align='left'>Email</td><td align='left'>".$_POST['email_share']."<br /></td></tr>"; 
$body.="</table>";

$headers = 'From: '.$from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($to, $email_subject, $body, $headers);
```

Comment: Nice and precise answer +1 for that