# How to send "HelloWorld" Email in magento2 via Controller?

Tags: magento2, email, smtp

I want to send the email to customer, please help me out with simple helloworld Program!!! Like Forget password Link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2: Send custom email programmatically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/287026/magento-2-send-custom-email-programmatically)

Comment: @MohitKumarArora It's different  from your question, already configured smtp.

Comment: welcome to Magento SE. If you think this is a different question, you can post whatever you have tried so far by editing your question and then someone can help you.